# How can I iterate through a multidimensional array without knowing it's depth?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, recursion, multidimensional-array

Since the nested input for my array is variable, the depth of it is variable as well. 
I know I can iterate through nested arrays in Ruby this way:

```
s.each do |sub_array|
    sub_array.each do |item|
        puts item
    end
end
```

But without knowing its depth beforehand, I won't have any success this way. 
Is the only possible way to write a recursive function ?

Comment: Fast & easy way is to `flatten` before iterating. But if you need to keep track of the nesting level at each iteration, you'll need a recursive solution. What information do you need in the block? Just `item`?

Comment: Don't use "(Ruby)" in the title. We can see it's about Ruby from the tags.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to use recursion in a case like this.

Comment: @josebert : It is always possible to change a recursive solution into an iterative one, see for instance [here](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html). Whether it is a good idea, is a different story. You may perhaps gain a little bit in performance (but not even this is guaranteed), but likely loose readability and maintainability.

Comment: Just now I got the idea of storing the nesting level as an instance variable, so i won't lose any information while flattening.
I'm writing a parser btw

Answer (score 0):

No, recursion is not the only way. It's possible to do this without recursion.

Iterating through an unknown depth nesting of arrays is exactly the same as doing a DFS walk through an unknown depth tree of nodes.

Although DFS is often represented recursively, you should be able to find a non-recursive example pretty easily.